# Address as a operand in sizeof() operator

Tags: c, sizeof

I was just trying an example and i tried to check the output when an address is passed as an argument in the `sizeof`
operator and i got output of 4. Now my question is when you pass a pointer in `sizeof` operator why is it showing 4 bytes of memory when actually there is no pointer variable, it's just only an address?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a=1;
  int c;
  c=sizeof(&a);
  printf("%d\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would there need to be a variable? `sizeof 42` is valid code, too.

Comment: Values (like an address) don't just exist in the ether. They have types too.

Comment: Since `sizeof` is an operator, the `()`s are not needed unless the argument is a type, in which case it's formatted as a cast expression to that type. Compare `sizeof (int)` and `(int) 1.2`, the `(int)` in both expressions is a cast.

Comment: @unwind can you explain in more detail,i don't understand

Comment: @user9121710 I was just trying to correct the way you put it in the title, the operator is `sizeof`, not `sizeof()`. Your code could (should, in my opinion) be written `sizeof &a`, since it's not a function call and there's no point in making it look like one.

Comment: @user9121710 The point made by unwind, though significant, was unnecessary and confusing, and has no bearing on the question you asked.  There's nothing wrong (in my opinion) with writing `sizeof(&a)`, even though the parentheses may be considered superfluous in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `sizeof` returns the size of a *type,* as per `C11 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators /2` (my emphasis):

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the ***type*** of the operand.

The type of `&a` where `a` is an `int` is covered by `6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators /3` in the same standard:

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. ***If the operand has type "type", the result has type "pointer to type".***

In other words, `int a; sizeof(&a)` is functionally equivalent to `sizeof(int *)`.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` operator works on the *type* of the operand.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4 (*emphasis mine*)

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand.** [....]

`&a` is of type `int *`, so your statement is the same as `sizeof(int *)`. The result, is the size of a pointer (to integer), in your platform.

That said, `sizeof` produces a type of `size_t` as result,

- use a variable of type `size_t`
- use `%zu` to print the result.